# Save output from ob-mermaid to the org-attach director

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I have recently started playing with the fantastic [ob-mermaid](https://github.com/arnm/ob-mermaid) (and its companion [mermaid-mode](https://github.com/abrochard/mermaid-mode)) package. Combined with the `mermaid CLI`, these let you generate [mermaid diagrams](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/) from `org-babel` source blocks. `ob-mermaid` requires a `:file` argument but I am wondering whether there is a way to redirect this to the default `org-attach` director?

Here is an example code block:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC mermaid :file graph_td.svg

graph TD
  start --> stop

#+END_SRC
```

Any ideas?